# Crystal Reports template is missing in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, crystal-reports

I could not find the Crystal Reports template in Visual Studio 2008 to create a Crystal Report.

So, after googling I found out that while installing I should have enabled the Crystal Report basic option. I did that also, but I could not find the Crystal Reports template while adding a new item, whereas in ToolBox under Reporting tab, it displays `CrystalReportViewer` and `CrystalReportDocument` controls.

What is the difference between adding a `CrystalReport` template or adding a `CrystalReportViewer`? Are `CrystalReportDocument` controls on a form working the same?

I am new to the Crystal Reports concept and usage. Can you please help me make the Crystal Reports template appear while adding new items in project.

The Visual Studio version is 2008 Professional Edition.

Comment: Repair or re-install the VS2008.

Comment: after reinstalling i could able to see the CrystalReportViewer,crystalreportdocument controls in toolbox.still i didn't see the crystal report template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be some help in this [blog post](http://chiragrdarji.wordpress.com/2008/05/06/missing-templates-in-visual-studio-installed-templates/) - especially in the comments.